# how to add Smooth scroll animation in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am using pure javascript for vertical scroll.I need this scroll to have smooth behaviour.

```js
function move_up(scroll_nav)
    {
        var container = document.getElementById(scroll_nav);
        upScroll(container,'up',40,50,10);

    }

    function move_down(scroll_nav)
    {
        var container = document.getElementById(scroll_nav);
        upScroll(container,'down',40,50,10);

    }

    function upScroll(element,direction,speed,distance,step)
    {
        scrollAmount = 0;
        var slideTimer = setInterval(function(){
            if(direction == 'up'){
                element.scrollTop  -= step;
            } else {
                element.scrollTop  += step;
            }
            scrollAmount += step;
            if(scrollAmount >= distance){
                window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
            }
        }, speed);
    }
```

I need an animate function similar to the one in this link but without jquery.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_smooth_scroll_jquery

I need an animate function to be included
Please provide an solution .

Answer (score 4):

`element.scrollTo({ top: ..., behavior: 'smooth' });`

Comment: No I want to have smooth animate effect.Thanks for your code

Comment: That's what `behavior: 'smooth'` does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions/behavior